# My domain name is followed by index.php ,when I open any webpage

Tags: php, wordpress, amazon-web-services

I'm developing website using wordpress, running on Ec2 instence. My issue is index.php is followed by all my pages.

so if my page is xyz and I open it, it will open as abc.com/index.php/xyz/ , while it should open as abc.com/xyz/

I have not used any permalink. I tried to change and remove index.php from perma link .It will stop working. All my files are in root directory. PLEASE solve my issue.

How can I get it to work directly as abc.com/xyz/ ?

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't have mod_rewrite enabled (if you are using Apache). Login to your EC2 instance, run `sudo a2enmod rewrite`, then restart apache `sudo service apache2 restart`. Make sure to update your `Permalink Settings` in Wordpress. Should work after that.

This question has also been asked numerous times on Stack Overflow already -- please [try searching](https://stackoverflow.com/search) next time.

Comment: I have checked with phpinfo(). My mod_rewrite is already enabled!

kindly suggest what's the issue?